# Rappaports algorithm for the convex hull of multiple circles.

Tags: geometry, reference-request, convex-geometry

I would like to use D. Rappaports convex hull algorithm for discs in a JavaScript application, which I am developing. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/092577219290015K

I found implementations of Andrew's monotone chain convex hull algorithm usable for points in a 2-dimensional space (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain). I guess I can somehow customize this algorithm to determine the convex hull of circles, it will however most likely not be in O(n log(n)).

I tried to understand and implement Rappaports algorithm, but without success. Does anyone know of resources that describes Rappoports convex hull algorithm in a more common language?

Best regards, Jesper

Comment: Are you aware of the paper "Incremental algorithms for finding the convex hulls of circles and the lower envelopes of parabolas" (Olivier DEVILLERS and Mordecai GOLIN) Information Processing Letters 56 (1995) 157-164 ? It's surely simpler.